# React-native app crashes after accessing second time the screen with in-app purchase

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase

I have a react-native app where I've implemented a module related to in-app purchase (to be more precise it's `react-native-iap`). The problem is that when I try to access by the second time the screen which has this functionality implemented, the app crashes, where can I find the log of this crash, and if possible, any ways to avoid this crash?

I've spotted this problem on an Android device, but i think that this one persists in iOS too...

Comment: did you manage to find a solution to this problem? I'm getting the same thing on android

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this on a release version? Because if you try to reproduce in debug you are supposed to have the red screen of react native which show you what was wrong (undefined object/function for example) and a stacktrace.

Comment: There does not appear any red screen, it just exits from the app and returns a message saying that the app has stopped

Comment: BTW, now I'm trying to test the purchase with test product IDs

Comment: When I use the ID `android.test.canceled` , and after performing the checkout, the app instantly closes and returns the message that it had stopped, while using the ID `android.test.purchsed`, on the second attempt of accessing the screen the sam actions are done by the app, but in the case of ID `android.test.item_unavailable`, it does everything as in the previous case, but returns the message tha the app keeps stopping...

Comment: Hmm it's strange that you don't see the red screen in debug mode. If you try with your app install from play store it is normal but if you try on a simulator or with react-native run-android on your device you should be able to see this red screen which can help you see what's wrong. Hmmm you could also try to put some alert in your code to determine where it crashs